# Range constraint numeric MySQL column: how?

Tags: mysql

Can I define a constraint on a numeric MySQL-column (InnoDB) to only allow values in a certain range?

For example column `wavelength` in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE spectrumdata
(
  valueid INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  spectrumset INT NOT NULL,
  wavelength DOUBLE NULL,
  intensity DOUBLE NULL,
  error INT NOT NULL,
  status INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (valueid),
  INDEX spectrumset_idx (spectrumset),
  CONSTRAINT spectrumset_fk FOREIGN KEY (spectrumset)
    REFERENCES spectrumsets (setid)
)
COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: Are you using InnoDB sir?

Comment: As MySQL is one of the very few DBMS to not support check constraints, your only chance is using a trigger.

Comment: @BlackHatShadow Yep, forgot to mention, sorry

Comment: Its ok. try my answer. I don't know the full specs of your table but that might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using InnoDB as Engine sir, you can [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249695/limit-the-value-of-a-mysql-datatype-to-a-specific-range-preferably-not-enum) out. As you can see, you can create a new table that contains your limiting values and reference to your field (as Foreign Key) it is now then enforce your constraint with referencial integrity.

**UPDATE**

try this:

```
   CREATE TABLE allowed_val(
      limiting_val DOUBLE NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (limiting_val )
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO allowed_val( limiting_val) VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),..(1000);

ALTER TABLE spectrumdata
ADD FOREIGN KEY (wavelength) REFERENCES allowed_val(limiting_val);
```

But you must also alter the `spectrumdata` wavelength to `NOT NULL` to DEFAULT = 0; to handle null values.

Comment: Thanks. But this is a workaround, I was wondering if there's a way forcing it by data definition statements, but it seems there isn't. I found the `CHECK` clause, but the documentation says: "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines". See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html

Comment: Also, your solution doesn't work for double values, only for integers. But thanks anyway