# How the Column will Accepts Limited Values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm working on MySQL Server 5.6.14.0, And Unable to find such kind of constraint which enable us to insert a limited values in a column or field. 
For Example, I want to declare a constraint in a columns which accepts only Value from 0 to 10 or A to Z, not more than that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249695/limit-the-value-of-a-mysql-datatype-to-a-specific-range-preferably-not-enum

Answer (score 0):

Just create a table with a column of allowed values and reference that in a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You can create insert/update trigger, which will check values inserted and throw error, here is example of throwing error: [How to raise an error within a MySQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465727/how-to-raise-an-error-within-a-mysql-function)