# Insert only Alphabets in a Field NOT Number in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.6, I want to declare such type of DATATYPE in a Field during table creation which accepts only Alphabets not Number, For Example, If I have a Column (Name) in a table, then I want it to accept only alphabets from A to Z, not Number or Numeric Value, varchar, char etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525944/how-the-column-will-accepts-limited-values-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

the data type is not the place to enforce your data integrity.  it's either chars or numbers, and numbers can be chars.  If you really need to enforce it at the db level vs in code (eg php) then you must do a stored procedure