# How to limit Value Range in tinyint(1) field?

Tags: mysql

I have a table TBLPRODUCTS.

The table contains a field **listed tinyint(1) not null default 0**

The field can take values between 0-9. **Is there a way in mysql to allow only two values in this field: either 1 or 0**

Comment: One possible solution provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9249893/

Comment: @AzizShaikh: I'd upvote that as an answer. Seems better than a trigger to emulate the non-functional CHECK constraint.

Comment: Actually, a `TINYINT(1)` can take 255 possible values, ranging from -128 and 127. You could use triggers (BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE), or a foreign key constraint.  With the foreign key constraint, you can raise an exception when a value is not in range. With triggers, you have more options as to how to handle values.

Comment: Where does the input come from? That's where I'd put the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert existing column to BIT(1), example sql

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE Persons MODIFY P_Id BIT(1) DEFAULT 0
```

Note: all existing values >=1 will be converted to 1;